# BLE Android to iOS chat

Tags: java

I am working on an app that allows Android and IOS devices to communicate to each other using Bluetooth. My IOS application is working fine, but I cannot get the android application to work. I am trying to make the android device my central. The problem I have encountered is that I am not able to scan for devices as when I do I get this message from the Android monitor:

> 08-07 15:09:30.983 27349-27364/uk.ac.york.androidtoios2
>   D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code that is not allowing me to scan for the peripheral IOS device.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothGatt gatt;
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic inputCharacteristic;
    private TextView outputView;
    private EditText inputView;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void receiveMode(View v) {
        int apiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (apiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            BluetoothLeScanner scanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
            // scan for devices
            scanner.startScan(new ScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                    // get the discovered device as you wish
                    // this will trigger each time a new device is found

                    BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // targeting kitkat or bellow
            bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    // get the discovered device as you wish
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // rest of your code that will run **before** callback is triggered since it's asynchronous



    public void sendMessage(View v) {
        inputCharacteristic.setValue(inputView.getText().toString());
        gatt.writeCharacteristic(inputCharacteristic);
    }


    BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

            if (getString(R.string.outputUUID).equals(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                final String value = characteristic.getStringValue(0);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        outputView.setText(value);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int newState) {
            MainActivity.this.gatt = gatt;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gatt.discoverServices();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
                    if (getString(R.string.outputUUID).equals(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
                        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptors().get(0);
                        if (descriptor != null) {
                            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                        }
                    } else if (getString(R.string.inputUUID).equals(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        inputCharacteristic = characteristic;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);
        inputView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =  (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new
                    Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your receiveMode() ?

Comment: Im not sure I undertsand the question? recieveMode is called when the button it is connected to is clicked

Comment: If you are targeting Android 6 or later, you must include additional code to ask the user for Location permissions in order to scan.

Comment: I do have the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission in the manifest but Im assuming you mean I need to ask for the permission in the main activity

Comment: I am running my app on a device using Android 5.1 so I dont think this is the issue